# Call a REST API using incron and bash script?

Tags: xml, linux, bash, shell, incron

I'm using incron to check if XML files are uploaded in a folder *Depot* using :

```
/home/parallels/Desktop/Depot IN_CLOSE_WRITE /home/parallels/Desktop/Depot/add.sh $#
```

When a new file is detected, the following bash script *add.sh* (which is in the *Depot* folder) is called :

```
#!/bin/bash
fileContent="$(cat $1)"

curl \
--header "Content-type: application/json" \
--request POST \
--data '{
    "user": "user@mail.com",
    "fileName": "'"$1"'",
    "content": "'"$fileContent"'"
}' \
http://url/of/the/api
```

The `$1` var contains the name of the file, and the `$fileContent` var contains the XML content of the file.

The thing is, when I manually call the bash script from the command line (when there's already a XML file in the *Depot* folder) using :

```
./add.sh test.xml
```

everything works fine. But when I try to trigger the script by dropping a new XML file into the folder, it doesn't do anything, despite showing-up in the log, `tail /var/log/syslog` command giving the following result :

```
(parallels) CMD (/home/parallels/Desktop/Depot/add.sh test.xml)
```

The only way I could get it working (by dropping a file in the folder) is when the content var is already set in the script, like so :

```
#!/bin/bash
fileContent="$(cat $1)" <=== Not used anymore in this case

curl \
--header "Content-type: application/json" \
--request POST \
--data '{
    "user": "user@mail.com",
    "fileName": "'"$1"'",
    "content": "
        <node>
            <subnode>
                content
            </subnode>
        </node>
"
}' \
http://url/of/the/api
```

Am I missing something here ? Should I use another method than `cat` to retrieve the XML content ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work !

I changed the incron command to :

```
/home/parallels/Desktop/Depot IN_CLOSE_WRITE /home/parallels/Desktop/Depot/add.sh #@/$#
```

and the bash script to :

```
#!/bin/bash
fileContent=`cat $1`
fileName=$(basename $1)

curl \
--header "Content-type: application/json" \
--request POST \
--data '
    {
        "user": "user@mail.com",
        "filename": "'"$fileName"'",
        "content": "'"$fileContent"'"
    }' \
http://url/of/the/api
```

I needed to send the full path of the file to the bash script (using $@/$#) for the cat function to work properly.